# Ignore entity when generating a migration on Symfony

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a mysql view and I am using it as an entity inside my project. But when generating a migration it tries to create a table. Is there a way to tell symfony to ignore that entity when generating a new migration?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="mysql_view_table")
 */
class MysqlViewTable {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The feature is ready (actually was merged 5 days ago), but not released yet. It will be included in the next (2.11) version. You will have option to set a list of entities to be ignored in the configuration:

```
$config->setSchemaIgnoreClasses([$fqcn]);
```

Docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/advanced-configuration.html#ignoring-entities-optional

PR: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/9202

Answer (score 1):

You can use this configuration to ignore the table `mysql_view_table`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(?!mysql_view_table)~
```

For more information, you can visite [DoctrineMigrationsBundle doc](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#manual-tables):

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my Symfony 6 Project.

I have on one hand entities that reference tables and on the other hand entities that reference views.

Now when creating a new migration with `php bin/console make:migration`, the migration file always contained commands to create tables that are actually views.

Example:

```
$this->addSql('CREATE TABLE address_view (id ...)
```

The following solution worked for me:

1. I created two subfolders in the App/Entity folder:

- Tables
- Views

2. All entities referencing views go into the Views folder and all others into the Tables folder
3. Under config/packages/doctrine.yaml the mapping directory has to be changed from "src/Entities" to "src/Entities/Tables". So it looks like this:

```
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
      App:
        is_bundle: false
        dir: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Tables"
        prefix: 'App\Entity'
        alias: App`
```

4. In the moved entity files the namespace must be adapted:

- Entities in the Views folder: namespace App\Entity\Views
- Entities in the Tables folder: namespace App\Entity\Tables
  In all files, e.g. Controller or FormTypes, in which the entities are used, the "use" statement must be adapted accordingly:
- Example: use App\Entity\Example -> use App\Entity\Tables\Example

I hope this may help you.